# dt.weekday works but dt.isoweekday doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract the year, month, date, day, minutes from column.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
2021-01-01 00:15:00
2021-01-02 00:30:00
2021-02-05 02:15:00
2021-02-20 00:15:00
2021-04-25 22:15:00
2021-12-30 00:10:00
```

I am trying:

```py
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['year'], df['month'], df['day'], df['minute'], df['hour'],df['weekday']=df['date'].dt.year, df['date'].dt.month, df['date'].dt.day, df['date'].dt.minute, df['date'].dt.hour,  df['date'].dt.isoweekday
df
```

Which works fine for all other attribute but `dt.isoweekday` is throwing error

> AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'isoweekday'

If I replace it with `dt.weekday` it works fine, but I need monday=1. I have also tried  `dt.Timestamp.isoweekday`, can any one please guide why isoweekday function is not working?

I am using pandas 1.3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the week day (1 being Monday), you need to use `df['date'].dt.isocalendar().day`:

```
0    5
1    6
2    5
3    6
4    7
5    4
Name: day, dtype: UInt32
```

Similarly, `df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week` would give you the ISO week number.

Note what with [`df['date'].dt.isocalendar()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isocalendar.html) you directly obtain year/week/day:

```
   year  week  day
0  2020    53    5
1  2020    53    6
2  2021     5    5
3  2021     7    6
4  2021    16    7
5  2021    52    4
```

Comment: df['date'].dt.isocalendar().week just prints number of week. I need weekday. df['date'].dt.isocalendar()  throws ValueError: Columns must be same length as key and if I use df['date'].dt.isocalendar it prints bound method DatetimeProperties.isocalendar o. in weekday column

Comment: if you want the weekday use `df['date'].dt.isocalendar().day`, 1 is Monday ;)